# Why both res & socket 'timeout' handler are triggered while I only call socket.emit('timeout')?

Tags: node.js, events, timeout, response

Why both res & socket 'timeout' handler are triggered
while I only call

```
socket.emit('timeout');
```

Not sure whether this is something obvious to you. Thank you.

[Output]

```
[Function]
[Function]
true
timeout
timeout2
```

[Code]

```
var http = require('http');

function http_relay(req, res){
    //console.log(res);
    console.log(req.socket === res.socket);
    //console.log(res.
    console.log(res.socket._events.timeout)
    console.log(res.connection._events.timeout)
    console.log(res.socket._events.timeout === res.connection._events.timeout)

    res.on('timeout',function(){
        //res.end();
        console.log('timeout');
    });

socket = res.socket;
    socket.on('timeout',function(){
        //res.end();
        console.log('timeout2');
    });

socket.emit('timeout');
//res.emit('timeout');
}


    ser = http.createServer(http_relay);

    ser.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there's an incoming http connection, the `http.ServerResponse` class hooks up a listener for the socket timeout event using this:

```
socket.on('timeout', ...)
```

and when it gets that event it then does this:

```
res.emit('timeout', ...)
```

The general idea is that the developer normally wouldn't interface directly with the `socket` itself, but rather just interact with the `response` object.

So, when you manually fire the timeout event on the socket, the response object's event listener sees that timeout event and the fires the timeout event on the response object.

You can see the code for that here in [the nodejs Github repository](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js#L393).

Comment: Thank you very much for both your explanation & your link. Now the flow is pretty clear to me. Flow:socket timeout event emitted -> socket timeout callback -> with this callback, res timeout event emitted -> res timeout callback.

Comment: @user1384726 - Yep, that's it exactly.  A huge advantage of programming with an open source library is that you can just go look at the code (if you can find the right piece of code with search) and see exactly what it's doing.

Comment: Before I doubt there's some relation between 'socket' class & 'response' class which cause the behavior. I do see 'socket' is attribute of 'response' by 'console.log'. However, that's the NOT the case. Again thank you for your explanation.